# Trigger para atualizar outra tabela

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, trigger

Tenho 4 tabela no meu banco de dados Mysql.
-> empresas
-> contatos (endereços das empresas)
-> dados_bancarios (dados bancarios da empresa)
-> socios (socios da empresa )

Todas tabelas relacionam com a tabela empresas.
Na tabela empresas tenho um campo updated_at, que gostaria que quando atualizasse qualquer das outras 3 tabelas, esse campo fosse atualizado.
Pensei em um TRIGGER, mas não sei como fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim:

```
CREATE TRIGGER socioup AFTER UPDATE
ON socios
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
   UPDATE empresas SET updated_at = NOW() WHERE empresa_id = new.empresa_id;
END
```

Comment: Realmente é isso que preciso, mas ele atualiza o updated_at de todas as empresas... tentei colocar algo do tipo: UPDATE empresas SET updated_at = NOW() WHERE empresa_id = contatos.empresa_id ... mas não deu certo

Comment: Hmmmm. Não sabia que você tem mais de uma empresa. Bom. O que tem na tabela sócios que define a empresa?

Comment: eu tenho uma coluna empresa_id que referencia a empresa

Comment: E na tabela empresas qual é a coluna que distingue as empresas?

Comment: também chama empresa_id

Comment: Alterei a resposta.

Comment: Show de bola. Mas não entendi como o new.empresa_id referencia o empresa_id da tabela dos sócios. poderia me explicar?

Comment: new.empresa é o valor que esta chegando para a trigger é a maneira da trigger lhe dizer qual é novo valor do campo empresa_id já que estamos no evento DEPOIS DO UPDATE. Siga a lógica e crie outras duas para as outras tabelas e pronto.